Passing integer via intent always returns default value
The value returned is always the default value when passing through getIntExtra. The snapshot value from Firebase by implementing count(). I have checked by printing count variable in the first activity, proving the value is correct (not the default value, 0). However, the value returned in second activity is always 0, the default value.
I have also checked by passing count as a string and retrieving using getStringExtra. The value returns null. The similar cases on StackOverflow have been checked, but no solution is found.
//first activity
val count = snapshot.count
val intent = Intent(this, Second::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
intent.putExtra("number", count)
finish()

//second activity
val returned = intent.getIntExtra("number", 0)
room.text = returned.toString()


"Problems arise when" is hard to help with here. What happens? Is there an error message? If not, what specific line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@FrankvanPuffelen Actually I am not familiar with firebase. I have updated the question. Just want to know the concept actually. Thank you

This looks weird: if (arrayList.toString().contains("CountID=2")). If you're trying to see if the list contains two items, how about if (arrayList.size == 2).

Why not just replace most of that code with the aggregate count function. That would really shorten the effort.

You are launching the second activity before passing parameter to intent and that's why the parameter always return default value.
Just swap these two lines and then try now this time you will get the exact behaviour:
startActivity(intent)
intent.putExtra("number", count)

